# How to have Java liked style static initialization in C++

Tags: c++

I was wondering, is it possible to have static initialization as Java style in C++? If not, what is the alternative way?

```
// .h
class A {
protected:
    static CBitmap bitmap;
};

// .cpp
CBitmap A::bitmap;
// Error!
static {
    global_initialization();
    bitmap.LoadBitmap(IDB_BITMAP);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this directly in C++ as you can in Java, but you can fake it in a few ways.  One option would be to have a static `bool` class variable that's initially false.  In the constructor, you can then do this:

```
MyClass::MyClass() {
    if (!staticInitialized) {
        /* ... */
        staticInitialized = true;
    }
}
```

This setup isn't thread-safe (though it can be made to be), and does the initialization as soon as the first class instance is created.

An alternative would be to do something like this in the .cpp file:

```
static class InitializeModule {
    InitializeModule() {
        /* ... */
    }
} instance;
```

This creates a singleton class local to the .cpp file whose constructor does the initialization.  This initialization is done at program start-time.

Comment: However, while instance has internal linkage, InitializeModule does not.  Using this name in another TU violates the ODR.  It is also strange to use a class only for the effect of the ctor, but there is no clean solution along these lines.

Comment: @Fred, can you not get around that with an anonymous namespace?

Comment: @Fred Nurk: Adding another static variable when RAII can do it automatically seems wasteful.

Comment: Note that the second technique should be used with care. The order global constructors are called in across translation units is undefined. In practice, changing the order that object files and libraries are linked in can break things if one global constructor depends on another global constructor being called first.

Comment: In real code, it is almost always best to either thread safely lazily initialize using something like pthread_once, or to require an initialize function is called from main explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: No

Long Answer: Yes
But you need to do some work and wrap your initialization code in a class.

Advantage of C++:
It requires slightly more code, but the same technique can be used to un-initialize the object when the program terminates. Saying that. This is one feature of Java that I would like to bring to C++. As in certain situations in can make the code less complicated (unfortunately like all features its abuse would make things worse).

```
class A
{
    class StaticBitMapInit: public CBitmap 
    {
        public:
            StaticBitMapInit()
            {
                global_initialization();
                this->LoadBitmap(IDB_BITMAP);
            }
            ~StaticBitMapInit()
            {
                // Uninitialized here
            }
    };
    protected:
        static StaticBitMapInit bitmap;
};

// .cpp
A::StaticBitMapInit  A::bitmap;
```

Comment: Although this *does* achieve what OP asked, I wouldn't recommend this.  Any error in `LoadBitmap()`, such as an exception, would occur before `main()` is ever executed.  You can't put a `try/catch` block around static initializers and `std::cout` etal. are not guaranteed to be already initialized.   Therefore, there is absolutely way to recover from any error.  Also, on Windows DLLs, the static initializers won't be executed (not sure about *NIX versions).

Comment: @André Caron: I agree with your basic point. Just a few things to note. std::cout is guaranteed to be initialized (but I am not sure what good that would do you Anything that goes wrong should probably be going to a log file anyway). DLL static initialize will be executed (if you link against the DLL). Though they may be delay initialized to the first time anything in the DLL is accessed (which is usually what you want).

Answer (score 0):

**If you're not worried about portability**

For Windows platforms on semi-recent versions of MSVC you can use `#pragma init_seg` to force the order in which things are initialized in a module.  Take a look [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/104248) for Microsoft's suggestions.

Note that the IBM C++ compiler and a few others also support this fashion of static initialization but not with the same syntax.